# Impact of creating multiple threads in REST Controller java

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have a REST Controller class. In that class there is one method, which has to execute 2 independent services parallelly as follows -

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String getResult(){
    //Call service 1
    // Call service 2
   // Combine the result and return
}
```

Since these two services can be independently executed, we are creating two threads in fixed thread pool and executing them parallelly. Now my question is since my REST API is getting called by thousands of users concurrently,
that means my code will create 1000*2 threads? Or it will create only 2 threads and shared across with multiple servlet threads?

Comment: Can you please share the code of creating the thread pool?

Comment: There will be 1000 + (1000*2) threads. As each API call is spanned on separate thread, so 1000 threads for API call, and each API call spans separate 2 threads, so (1000*2). So total 3000 threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your ThreadPool is defined outside of the method at application level. That is the right thing to do. So you will have two worker threads across the application(a single JVM instance).

Now suppose, you are getting 1000 requests from the users simultaneously. Then your application will create 1000 HTTP threads. And these 1000 HTTP threads will fight for the two worker threads that you have defined in Executor thread pool. So it will choke the application. Response time will go higher increasingly as HTTP threads will wait till they have access to thread pool. And eventually it will eat up the resources of your application.

So you need to increase the size of your thread pool accordingly.

Comment: Thread pool is defined inside method and not class level

Comment: That is not a good idea. Thread pool is used so that you can control the number of threads. If it is inside the method, you will create new thread pool every time a request comes. So you will have 1000 * 2 worker threads. Too many threads can kill the application as threads take their own resources. That's why thread pool is used. It also helps in reducing the creation overhead of new threads. But the way you are using, you are not taking any advantages of thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see that creating thread pool at class level is not good idea and creating at method level is also not good idea. What do you think is the best approach to handle this scenario?

Comment: Thread pool should be created at application level. An application can have multiple thread pools, with their own configurations as per modules in which it is being used.

Comment: Class level (application level) is good idea. But 2 worker threads for 1000 requests won't be good enough. You need to increase the size to 100 or 200 maybe. Depends on the server configuration. You would have to do a load test on that.